# Ionic 3 diagnostic plugin not working throwing aapt error and processDebubgResource error

Tags: typescript, ionic3, diagnostics

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic
npm install --save @ionic-native/diagnostic@4
```

used the above command to install diagnostic plugin inside my project

I am using a windows machine

```
Installed platforms:
  android 6.3.0
  ios 4.5.5
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~6.0.0

cordova.plugins.diagnostic 4.0.12 "Diagnostic"
```

when building it shows error

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Comment: You should put more info like the error code, etc.

Comment: edited and updated  @distante

Comment: Make sure the Android SDK version in the gradle.build of your app matches the version of the plugin's SDK version.

Comment: i have update my question please  go through it and correct me @Jay Ordway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed my android platform using

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

and added it again using

```
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

resulted in android 8.0.0

and when i ran the code it showed some SDK error to update license which you can easily solve by
moving into android sdk location
:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin

Run command

```
sdkmanager --licenses
```

Accept the licence for SDK

Comment: In ionic 3, showing this error "AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.". And now it is fixed with your solution. Thanks.